# Java game difficulty level

Tags: java

I need some help with the java squash or tennis game that i'm making, when selecting the difficulty level, i want the racquet size to decrease in half and the ball to move more fast. I have implemented the ball to move fast, but i can't seem to find a way to decrease the size of the racquet. Here is my "difficultylevel" class:
Also, how can I implement a MOUSEDRAGGED option to move the racquet?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class DifficultyLevel extends JPanel {
private JButton aButton = new JButton("Exit Game");
private Game sg;
private MainFrame sf;
private int selection;
//JRadioButton easyButton, mediumButton, hardButton;
JComboBox<String> difficulty;
ButtonGroup radioGroup;

private void changeDiff(){
    if (selection == 0){
        sg.speed=1;
        sg.Score=0;
        sg.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }else if (selection == 1){
        sg.speed=2;
        sg.Score=0;
        sg.setBackground(Color.pink);

    }if (selection == 2){
        sg.speed=3;
        sg.Score=0;
        sg.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
}

public DifficultyLevel(Game g, MainFrame sfr){

    sg = g;
    sf = sfr;

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    difficulty = new JComboBox<String>();

    difficulty.addItem("Easy");
    difficulty.addItem("Medium");
    difficulty.addItem("Hard");
    difficulty.setSelectedIndex(0);
    changeDiff();
    add(difficulty);

    difficulty.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            selection = difficulty.getSelectedIndex();
            changeDiff();
        }
    });

}
}
```

And here is my Racquet class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;

public class Racquet {
private static final int Y = 330;
private static final int WIDTH = 60;
private static final int HEIGHT = 10;

int x = 0;
int xa = 0;

private Game game;

public Racquet(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth() - WIDTH)
        x = x + xa;
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        xa = -1;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = 1;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public int getTopY() {
    return Y;
}

public void mouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent m){

    if(m.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL)
        xa = -1;
    if(m.getWheelRotation() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL)
        xa = 1;

}
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent m) {
    xa = 0;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your Racket class you must delete final and static to WIDTH and then in the Racket's constructor add width:

```
public Racket(Game game, int width) {
     this.width = width;
}
```

When the Racket is created if the difficulty is hard:

```
Racket(game, 20);
```

And when it's simple:

```
Racket(game, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i deleted the final and static from WIDTH and added the constructor, however, when I add Racket(game, 20); into the difficulty level class, it's showing an error saying that "game cannot be resolved to a variable)